# Couchbase Disk Usage

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I'm using Couchbase, with .net - Latest CouchbaseNetClient.

Couchbase Serer 4.6.2 Enterprise running.

I have an app where It performs 5k/ops.

The problem I am facing - is as soon as I start this app - then the CPU usage jumps to 100% and Disk Usage jumps to 100% also (as noted on the ctrl+alt+del ->Performance->Disk 0 (C:)

I have tested across a few PC.s - All are SSD (Samsung 850 PRO) and a dell M.2. Both have excellent r/w capabilities which I would have thought would swallow 5k ops.

The machine with the 850 PRO is a 6c/12t 980x CPU.
The machine with the m2.dell is a 4c/8t i76700hq.

I'm using a standard Upsert as per couchbase doco's. When I comment out this line, CPU goes right down to expected levels.

Is there some form of tweaking/performance/indexing mechanism I am missing entirely here??

Regards,

Chud

EDIT #1

So I uninstalled Couchbase on the Dell XPS and reinstalled it as memcached server only. Funny thing is, the CPU goes to 100% and now disk stays at 0% (expected of course). I have commented out the lines that actually do the Upsert, and CPU usage remains virtually unchanged to what it was before I started the app, even though the app itself is still doing a fair bit of crunching, it's just not entering the data into the (now) memcached database.

How can the upsert be so so so expensive? It's only a small Json file...

EDIT #2

So here is some samples that may get you going. I have changed the models around a some what to keep confidentiality in what I am doing, so it is "untested" so to speak. So if there are bugs in this I apologise, I literally just hacked it together.

Json Sample Below - I guess put this in a loop and let it rain, see if you can produce the same load.

```
{"Position":10,"Type":0,"Type2":5,"Value":0.0,"Type3":1,"Location":"Bla","Type":"Ex","Id":"11111"}

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public MyFirstType Type { get; set; }
        public MySecondType Type2 { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public MyThirdType Type3 { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MyFirstType
    {
        A,
        B
    }

    public enum MySecondType
    {
        C,
        D,
        E,
        F,
        G,
        H
    }

    public enum MyThirdType
    {
        I,
        J
    }
    public class CouchBaseInstanceTest
    {
        private Cluster CouchClient;
        private IBucket Bucket;

        public CouchBaseInstanceTest()
        {
            CouchClient = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration
            {
                Servers = new List<Uri> {new Uri("http://localhost:8091")}

            });
            // I think CB v 5.0 and over, or 5.5 needs auth against the bucket
            //CouchClient.Authenticate("admin", "password");  
            Bucket = CouchClient.OpenBucket("default");
        }
        public bool Upsert(string key, dynamic value, double expiry)
        {
            var Document = new Document<dynamic>()
            {
                Id = key,
                Content = value,
                Expiry = TimeSpan.FromHours(expiry).ToTtl()
            };
            return Bucket.Upsert(Document).Success;
        }
    }
```

So as soon as that Bucket.Upsert is hit - the CPU/Disk maxes out.... or in just the memcached config....the CPU maxes out....

To be honest though, the code here is really irrelevant I think. When I replaced the document values with a blank string "" - The problem was still the same

Comment: Sounds like you should ask this on github or where ever this is located.

Comment: Could you post the minimum code to recreate this? It's possible that you're creating too many connections or something like that.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I actually use a DI Container to establish the connection. This is only done once on program startup, and then the only thing called is an Upsert Function. I have even tried to use the Upsert(Dictionary<string,dynamic> "bulk"  type function, but it makes no difference.